# Função para realizar divisão de duas colunas

Tags: android, r, script, packages, interpretador

Estou iniciando no R Studio e não sei como faço para obter dados percapita (que no caso seria a divisão da coluna valor pela coluna população)

Comment: Por favor, edite a pergunta para limitá-la a um problema específico com detalhes suficientes para identificar uma resposta adequada.

Answer (score 2):

#Você poderia usar a função `mutate` para isso. Em um exemplo hipotético vc poderia fazer:

```
library(tidyverse)

pop<-c(100,200,300)
PIB<-c(20000,30000,35000)
muni<-c('A','B','C')

dados<-data.frame(pop,PIB,muni)
```

pop
PIB muni

100 20000   A
200 30000   B
300 35000   C

Calculando o valor per capta usando a função `mutate` aplicada ao data.frame de exemplo

```
dados%>%
mutate(percapta=(PIB/pop))

dados
```

pop

PIB

muni

percapta

100 20000   A   200.0000
200 30000   B   150.0000
300 35000   C   116.6667